# Problema com chamada em Banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal seguinte eu tenho varias chamadas que vão atualizando um banco de dados a medida que o usuário vai preenchendo os campos porém especificamente na seguinte chamada da erro no banco de dados e não salva por nada, sendo que todas utilizam as mesmas chamadas só mudando os dados. Alguém consegue enchergar algum erro nesta chamada que não estou vendo?

```
if($op == 4) { 

$rg = $_POST["RG"];
$orgao = $_POST["orgao_rg"];
$cpf = $_POST["CPF"];
$fotofrente = $_POST["foto-id-frente"];
$fotoverso = $_POST["foto-id-verso"];

if($_POST["foto-id-frente"] && $_POST["foto-id-verso"]){
    usleep(enviar());
}

if(isset($_FILES['foto-id-frente']) && isset($_FILES['foto-id-verso'])){

    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto-id-frente']['name'],-4));
    $novonome = md5(time()).$extensao;
    $extensaoverso = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto-id-verso']['name'],-4));
    $novonomeverso = md5(time()).'verso'.$extensaoverso;
    $diretorio = "documentos/";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto-id-frente']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novonome);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto-id-verso']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novonomeverso);

    $inserir = "UPDATE usuarios ";

    $inserir .= "SET ";

    $inserir .= "identidade = '$rg', orgao-id = '$orgao', foto-id-frente = '$novonome', foto-id-verso = '$novonomeverso', CPF = '$cpf' where id = '$id'";



    $operacao_inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserir);

    if(!$operacao_inserir) {

        echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Opss, erro no cadastro do banco de dados, estamos tentando corrigir!');</script>";

            die();

    }


}
```

}

Comment: `na seguinte chamada da erro no banco de dados e não salva por nada`. Ok, mas qual é o erro que ocorre ? Adicione na pergunta para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na seguinte linha:

```
$operacao_inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserir);
```

adicione o *mysqli_error* para saber o que há de erro assim:

```
$operacao_inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserir) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Mas uma coisa, vi que você possui um campo do banco separado por hífen, no caso *orgao-id*, quando se usa um campo assim, você precisa colocar entre aspas simples ou crase: *'orgao-id'*, ou ao invés de usar hífen, use underline.

Comment: Quando uso o mysqli_error() não mostra nada, parece que o erro não é no sql... buguei agora kkkk

Comment: @MarlonHenrique então é a segunda parte que mencionei sobre as aspas em campos separados por hífen

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema colocando a consulta no seguinte formato:

```
    $inserir = "UPDATE `usuarios` ";

    $inserir .= " SET ";

    $inserir .= " `identidade` = '$rg', `orgao-id` = '$orgao', `foto-id-frente` = '$novonome', `foto-id-verso` = '$novonomeverso', `CPF` = '$cpf' WHERE `usuarios`.`id` = $id ";

    $operacao_inserir = mysqli_query($conexao,$inserir);
```

Comment: Então, o erro estava exatamente conforme eu havia falado em minha resposta acima, em que quando se usa um campo do banco de dados que é separado por hífen, é necessário usar algum tipo de aspas nele, caso contrário, o banco não reconhece.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado amigo

Comment: Por nada, estamos para ajudar